# Bluetooth status: inactive (dead)

Tags: drivers, 15.04, bluetooth

When I try to activate usb on my laptop, I can't see my device.  I see the message below when I request the status of bluetooth.

```
 bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service


Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

How can I activate it?

Comment: What is YOUR LAPTOP? Which Ubuntu version is installed? Please add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use systemctl to start the Bluetooth service

```
systemctl start bluetooth
```

Answer (score 6):

To check the status of your Bluetooth, use:

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
```

Then consider two possible solutions:

1. Enable bluetooth via `systemctl`:

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service
   ```
2. Check if your bluetooth is blacklisted:

   1. `sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
   2. If the file has `blacklist btusb`, exit out of the file and run :

      ```
      sudo modprobe btusb
      ```

This should enable Bluetooth.

Since your Bluetooth is dead, the second solution is likely to help you.

Comment: `modprobe ...` was the missing link for me, even if not blacklsted, at least in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.