# Ubuntu 22.04 Settings: "No Bluetooth Found - Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth"

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, 22.04

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on my HP laptop model 15-dy2xxx. Before I had triple-booted with Windows 10, Ubuntu 16.04, and Ubuntu 20.04 for various OS-dependent
software, but this time I chose the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option to keep everything cleaner. I installed it with an ISO file from ubuntu.com by creating a bootable USB with Rufus on Windows, following the official tutorials: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop and https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows. Installation and setup went relatively smoothly.

But today I tried to use Bluetooth for the first time, and in the Bluetooth section of Settings all I see is the message "No Bluetooth Found - Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth". The switch to enable Bluetooth can't be clicked on. I used Bluetooth just fine on Ubuntu 20.04, I've only had issues since reinstalling the new Ubuntu version.

A lot of answers I found online are for older versions of Ubuntu, which don't seem to be helpful because again I had no issues with my previous installation.

---

The closest I've gotten to a solution is as follows. When I run these status commands I get this output:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i blue
$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
○ bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Aug 31 19:39:03 zach-HP-Laptop-15-dy2xxx systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

Then I run these commands *in order* (any other order causes error messages as far as I can tell):

```
$ sudo modprobe btusb
$ sudo rmmod btusb
$ sudo systemctl start bluetooth
```

And the output of the previous set of commands changes to this:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[  161.311841] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  161.311868] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[  161.311868] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  161.311871] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  161.311873] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  161.311875] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  170.442648] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  170.442651] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  170.442654] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-08-31 20:10:23 PDT; 2min 17s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 3482 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9029)
     Memory: 1.8M
        CPU: 29ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─3482 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Aug 31 20:10:23 zach-HP-Laptop-15-dy2xxx systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Aug 31 20:10:23 zach-HP-Laptop-15-dy2xxx bluetoothd[3482]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Aug 31 20:10:23 zach-HP-Laptop-15-dy2xxx systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Aug 31 20:10:23 zach-HP-Laptop-15-dy2xxx bluetoothd[3482]: Starting SDP server
Aug 31 20:10:23 zach-HP-Laptop-15-dy2xxx bluetoothd[3482]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21 initialized
```

Which implies that the problem has been fixed, or at least part of it. Unfortunately, I have the same message in the Settings menu, and the changes seem to get reverted if I restart my laptop (the status commands switch back to the first set of outputs). I don't know enough about this software to know what to do from this point.

---

Some of the other things I've tried (some of them have overlap):

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1404004/1627995 - No effect.
- https://askubuntu.com/a/649505/1627995 - HTTP 404 error when running `wget`.
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1403819/1627995 - No effect. I also tried the commands in that answer's comments, but `sudo hciconfig hci0 down` gives me the output `Can't get device info: No such device`. I tried looking up solutions for this, but they all seemed to be about Raspberry Pis or different distros.
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1179543/1627995 - No effect.
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1304456/1627995 - No effect.
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1161750/1627995 - Switched to a Realtek WiFi driver option, no effect.

Outputs from various suggested commands:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
0000:01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    DeviceName: Realtek Wireless LAN + BT
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:884d]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8821ce
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce
10000:e0:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 [8086:a0b0] (rev 20)
```

```
$ lsusb;
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c00 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0408:5365 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
$ ls -lah /etc/modprobe.d/
total 60K
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Aug 31 18:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 140 root root  12K Aug 31 17:45 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 2.5K Feb 22  2021 alsa-base.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  154 Oct  7  2021 amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  325 Aug 17  2021 blacklist-ath_pci.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1.5K Aug 17  2021 blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  210 Aug 17  2021 blacklist-firewire.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  677 Aug 17  2021 blacklist-framebuffer.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  156 Feb 22  2021 blacklist-modem.conf
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   41 Aug 30 18:45 blacklist-oss.conf -> /lib/linux-sound-base/noOSS.modprobe.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  583 Aug 17  2021 blacklist-rare-network.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  154 May 15 23:44 intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  347 Aug 17  2021 iwlwifi.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   23 Sep 26  2017 libopenni-sensor-pointclouds0.conf
```

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
Restarting bluetooth (via systemctl): bluetooth.service.
```

```
$ hcitool scan
Device is not available: No such device
```

```
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 inqmode 0
Can't get device info: No such device
```

```
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
```

To me it looks like driver(s) can't find the Bluetooth adapter, but I'm not sure what to do about that.

Comment: Laptops generally have a "disable bluetooth" key/button, somewhere around the keyboard. Have you mistakenly pushed it? Check the manual for your laptop,  available from `hp.com`

Comment: @waltinator None of the keys have a Bluetooth symbol or otherwise seem to be related to networks (besides an Airplane Mode key, which I tested). I searched Google for some kind of Bluetooth button, but all of the answers were software-side and only for Windows. I also found an [HP 15 laptop manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c08289069.pdf) and searched for "Bluetooth," but the only results were hardware specs. Besides, if I had accidentally pressed a key then I think it would have reset when I restarted my laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just now I booted up my PC after the battery died and the Bluetooth settings have appeared. The Bluetooth menu in the Settings is showing nearby devices instead of the "No Bluetooth Found" message, and a Bluetooth section was added to the system menu. I've restarted and shut down my PC several times while trying solutions online, but they had no effect until just now.

The status commands that I tried above are showing the Bluetooth device as active now:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c00 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0408:5365 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b00e Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ rfkill list all
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    14:13:33:2D:46:A4
```

My problem is resolved, but unfortunately I'm not completely sure what the solution was. My best guess is that it was fixed by the last suggestion I tried (enabling the Realtek WiFi driver): https://askubuntu.com/a/1161750/1627995.

The exact steps I followed were opening the "Software & Updates" app, going to "Additional Drivers," selecting "Using DKMS source for the Realtek 8821C PCIe Wi-Fi driver from rtl8821ce-dkms (open source)," and clicking "Apply Changes."

Restarting had no effect at the time, but it seems to have worked now. Maybe after installing drivers, my laptop needed to be powered off and turned back on, *not* just restarted. A few suggestions I found online indicated that shutting down can sometimes be more effective than restarting, but I had forgotten to try that after changing the driver.

Comment: I tried several other methods but this was the only one that worked. My guess is that the used of the non open source driver has to be manually reauthorized after the Ubuntu 20 to 22 upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

Performing a power flush will fix the bluetooth issue on Ubuntu. That's what worked for me on my Asus TUF A15.

1. Press and hold the power button of your laptop till all the lights go off
2. Leave it for a few seconds (5-6)
3. Power on the laptop