# bluetooth not working ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, command-line, drivers, 22.04, bluetooth

its the same problem where you toggle on and off bluetooth in the settings but nothing works. please help. its appriciated.
ive tried reinstalling bluetooth and bluez. and tried $ service bluetooth status shows running. tried turning on and off bluetooth service but nothing.

[image]

Comment: at this point my guess is maybe my laptop adapter is not supported by the driver or something.

Comment: By what driver? What does nothing works mean? What device are you trying to connect? Do you know the device works ? You need a lot more details added to the question using the edit feature.

Comment: sure aaa so, im trying to connect any bluetooth device. none of them work. basically when you turn the bluetooth toggle on/off in the settings, it shows nothing. (i added a screenshot). i do not exactly know which driver/ adapter i have in my laptop. but it is an asus strix g15 2022.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please, try the lsusb command, is the bluetooth adapter in the list?

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. Hopefully this will solve your problem: https://askubuntu.com/a/1485928/1731074

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Worked for me, thanks!